# Angular RxJs timer pausing on IE11

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, angular-cli

I have a timer that periodically pumps data into the main page of my Angular4 app. For Chrome, everything is working just fine. However, IE11 will sometimes get into a mode where the Observable, and actually even the Observables that are not on a timer (on other pages), will pump out old data. While Chrome is going along just fine getting new data, IE is stuck with numbers it had from a period of time in the past. When I navigate to other pages, everything is stuck in the past, so all the data is consistent (but out of date).

Reloading the browser has no effect, navigating to different pages has no effect. The only way I can get the Observables to start pumping out new data again (without closing and restarting the browser) is to open the development tools, go to the network page and start network monitoring. Then it seems to kick back in.

Anybody else experiencing this or know what might be causing it?

Additional Info.

I notice that if I leave the developer tools open for IE, that I get this error coming out after a while from a reference called webpack///webpack bootstrapxxxxxxxxxx (where the x's are some numbers in hex). The stop point is:

```
// The require function
function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

    // Check if module is in cache
    if(installedModules[moduleId])
        return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

    // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
        i: moduleId,
        l: false,
        exports: {}
    };

    // Execute the module function
    modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

    // Flag the module as loaded
    module.l = true;

    // Return the exports of the module
    return module.exports;
}
```

With this error under "modules[moduleId].call...

```
Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference
```

Comment: I've added some additional information.

Comment: having same issue...IE does not use observable timer unless debug window is open. why??!!!