# Webpack Issues in IE11

Tags: webpack, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code:

```
var result = __webpack_require__(806);

    if (typeof result === "string") {
        module.exports = result;
    } else {
        module.exports = result.toString();
    }
```

And am receiving the following error only while testing in Internet Explorer 11: `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error`

I also get that: '**webpack_require**' is undefined

Are there any workarounds for this in IE11? Things are working fine in Chrome, Firefox and EDGE.

I was referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358349/webpack-breaking-in-ie11) and [this](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/213) and was wondering if I was headed in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

I've read this [interesting article](https://hackernoon.com/polyfills-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-or-maybe-a-bit-less-7c8de164e423) and was wondering if I should be using a [polyfill service](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/) or sticking with `babel-polyfill` ?

Thanks